# PyQt, вывод списока ссылок

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Делаю виджет для вывода списка ссылок из rss ленты. Если использовать WebView, то ссылки нормально выводятся, но только открываются в том же WebView. А мне хочется, что-бы они открывались через QDesktopServices.openUrl(), т.е. через стандартный браузер системы.
Как это можно вывести список ссылок, что-бы по клику каждая открывалась в новом окне стандартного браузера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение - использовать тот же WebView, только изменить Link Delegation Policy

```
 webview.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
```

И повесить обработчик на сигнал:

```
 def linkClicked(url):
            webbrowser.open(str(url.toString()))
 self.webview.connect(self.webview.page(), SIGNAL("linkClicked (const QUrl&)"), linkClicked)
```